# Failed Binder Transaction text file

Tags: android, android-binder

I have to read some datas from text file with 96000 bytes so that I can plot a line Graph. I've tried to read every 2 byte and combine them in 2 byte and then I made 8 arrays with 6000 integer each.But I'm having the mentioned error!!
If I try to use only 1,2 or 3 Arrays it works but from 4 array doesn't

Can someone help me please to see where I'm doing wrong.
I've read from yesterday different discussions and didn't really see any appropriate answer.
What I got is that it is the Problem with the memory/heap.

here are my code.

```
byte LSB;
     byte MSB;
    public  Intent getIntent(Context context) throws IOException{
        InputStream data_in ;

            data_in = context.getAssets().open("demodta.txt");

             int[] x = new int[6000]; // x values
             int[] y1= new int[6000]; // y1 values
             int[] y2= new int[6000]; // y2 values
             int[] y3= new int[6000]; // y3 values
             int[] y4= new int[6000]; // y4 values
             int[] y5= new int[6000]; // y5 values
             int[] y6= new int[6000]; // y6 values
             int[] y7= new int[6000]; // y7 values
             int[] y8= new int[6000]; // y8 values  
             int i =0;


//      while(true) {
    int j=0;
         try {

         int size = data_in.available();
         byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
         data_in.read(buffer);

             for( i=0;i<12000;i=i+2){                
                 LSB =  buffer[i];
                 MSB = buffer[i+1];
                  int current= ((MSB<<8)| (LSB & 0xFF));
                y1[j]=  current;
                j++;
              }
                j=0;
             for(i=12000;i<24000;i=i+2){
                LSB =  buffer[i];
                MSB = buffer[i+1];
                int current= ((MSB<<8)| (LSB & 0xFF));
                y2[j]=  current;
                j++;
              }
             j=0;
             for(i=24000;i<36000;i=i+2){
                LSB =  buffer[i];
                 MSB = buffer[i+1];
                 int current= ((MSB<<8)| (LSB & 0xFF));
                 y3[j]=  current;
                 j++;
               }
             j=0;
             for(i=36000;i<48000;i=i+2){
                LSB =  buffer[i];
                 MSB = buffer[i+1];
                 int current= ((MSB<<8)| (LSB & 0xFF));
                 y4[j]=  current;
                 j++;
               }
             j=0;
             for(i=48000;i<60000;i=i+2){
                LSB =  buffer[i];
                 MSB = buffer[i+1];
                 int current= ((MSB<<8)| (LSB & 0xFF));
                 y5[j]=  current;
                 j++;
               }
             j=0;
             for(i=60000;i<72000;i=i+2){
                LSB =  buffer[i];
                 MSB = buffer[i+1];
                 int current= ((MSB<<8)| (LSB & 0xFF));
                 y6[j]=  current;
                 j++;
               }
             j=0;
             for(i=72000;i<84000;i=i+2){
                LSB =  buffer[i];
                 MSB = buffer[i+1];
                 int current= ((MSB<<8)| (LSB & 0xFF));
                 y7[j]=  current;
                 j++;
               }
             j=0;
             for(i=84000;i<96000;i=i+2){
                LSB =  buffer[i];
                 MSB = buffer[i+1];
                 int current= ((MSB<<8)| (LSB & 0xFF));
                 y8[j]=  current;
                 j++;
               }
         }

 for(int k=0;k<6000;k++){
     x[k]=k;
    }

        TimeSeries series1 = new TimeSeries("line1");
        for(int k=0;k<x.length;k++){
            series1.add(x[k], y1[k]);
        }
        TimeSeries series2 = new TimeSeries("line2");
        for(int k=0;k<x.length;k++){
            series2.add(x[k], y2[k]);
        }
        TimeSeries series3 = new TimeSeries("line3");
        for(int k=0;k<x.length;k++){
            series3.add(x[k], y3[k]);
        }
        TimeSeries series4 = new TimeSeries("line4");
        for(int k=0;k<x.length;k++){
            series4.add(x[k], y4[k]);
        }
        TimeSeries series5 = new TimeSeries("line5");
        for(int k=0;k<x.length;k++){
            series5.add(x[k], y5[k]);
        }
        TimeSeries series6 = new TimeSeries("line6");
        for(int k=0;k<x.length;k++){
            series6.add(x[k], y6[k]);
        }
        TimeSeries series7 = new TimeSeries("line7");
        for(int k=0;k<x.length;k++){
            series7.add(x[k], y7[k]);
        }
        TimeSeries series8 = new TimeSeries("line8");
        for(int k=0;k<x.length;k++){
            series8.add(x[k], y8[k]);
        }
```

here is my MainActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button strt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LineGraph);

        strt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                lineGraph line = new lineGraph();

                Intent lineIntent = null;
                try {
                    lineIntent = line.getIntent(getBaseContext());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                startActivity(lineIntent);

            }
        });
    }
```

my LogCat gives the following output:

```
05-27 19:39:00.180: D/dalvikvm(5556): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 10% free 14410K/15879K, paused 68ms
05-27 19:39:00.750: D/dalvikvm(5556): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 961K, 16% free 13452K/15879K, paused 72ms
05-27 19:39:00.830: D/dalvikvm(5556): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 10% free 14348K/15879K, paused 77ms
05-27 19:39:00.830: I/dalvikvm-heap(5556): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.945MB for 917520-byte allocation
05-27 19:39:00.920: D/dalvikvm(5556): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 10% free 15244K/16839K, paused 78ms
05-27 19:39:01.320: D/dalvikvm(5556): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1206K, 15% free 14407K/16839K, paused 74ms
05-27 19:39:01.320: I/dalvikvm-heap(5556): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.643MB for 1589467-byte allocation
05-27 19:39:01.410: D/dalvikvm(5556): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 14% free 15958K/18439K, paused 73ms
05-27 19:39:01.420: E/JavaBinder(5556): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

Comment: what is the size of your demodta.txt file??

Comment: can't you reuse the arrays.. you dont have heap memory left..

Comment: how? what can I do to get the heap free.Because the size of the file is too small, I don't think is the one who causes the problem!

Comment: Your arrays are causing the heap to be full. You are allocating around 54k of memory..

Comment: can you give me a tip please how i can do it!!!

Comment: why dont you plot the graph for y1 first and then populate new values in y1. fill - plot -> refill new values - plot

Comment: Hey Tarun, sorry if I seem to not really realise what u told me
 I have tried to do what you you said but I don't get it.
I think according to what you said I have to repaint the graph after refilling y1. Am I right? And that I don't know how to do.
Can you please give me a little bit details. Thx again

Comment: Couldnt you do this way.. `
`for( i=0;i<12000;i=i+2){                
y1[j]=  current;
j++;
}`
`
TimeSeries series1 = new TimeSeries("line1");
for(int k=0;k<x.length;k++){
series1.add(x[k], y1[k]);
}
`
`
for(i=12000;i<24000;i=i+2){
y1[j]=  current;
j++;
}`

Comment: I will add my comment as an answer and plz mark it as accepted..

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt you do this way..

```
 for( i=0;i<12000;i=i+2){ y1[j]= current; j++; }
 TimeSeries series1 = new TimeSeries("line1"); 
for(int k=0;k<x.length;k++){ series1.add(x[k], y1[k]); } 
 for(i=12000;i<24000;i=i+2){ y1[j]= current; j++; }
```